# Error using string::erase in C++

Tags: c++

I'm having an error while compiling my C++ program. Below is my code!

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include "Path.h"
#include "Maze.h"
#include "SubmitMazeSoln.h"
#include "Assignm3_Utils.h"
#include "Assignm3.h"

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

srand(time(NULL));
string random = "0123";

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    int x = (rand () % random.size());
    char y = random[x];

    random.erase(remove(random.begin(), random.end() + y), random.end());

    int temp;
        if (threadData.threadIDArrayIndex == 0)
        {
            temp = i;
        }

        else
        {
            temp = y - '0';
        }
}
```

The error when I compile my program.

```
myprog.cpp: In function ‘void* exploreMaze(void*)’:
myprog.cpp:108:56: error: cannot convert ‘std::basic_string<char>::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >}’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int remove(const char*)’
random.erase(remove(random.begin(), random.end() + y), random.end());
```

Sorry guys help is deeply appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Where's the function executing your code?? Don't you at least need a `main()` function to start with?

Comment: One issue is the arguments to remove, I think you should have ' , y)' not ' + y)'. a more complete example would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

As DaveB says,

```
remove(random.begin(), random.end() + y)
```

should be

```
remove(random.begin(), random.end(), y)
```

The error message is confusing because `random.end() + y` is a valid expression, although it produces an iterator that's way off the end of the container. So the compiler sees a call to the function `remove` with two arguments, and tries to make sense of it. The compiler sees a function with the signature `remove(const char*)`, and guesses that that's what you meant, then complains that it can't convert the first argument to type `const char*`.

This confusion wouldn't have happened if you used proper C++ standard library names such as `std::remove`. `using namespace std;` strikes again!